# How do I implement an internally populated blacklist?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm writing a token contract that accepts and and issues varying  ether/token amounts via conditional statements  like so:

```
function getAirdrop() public payable {
    if (msg.value < 0.005 ether) {
       balances[msg.sender] += 4000;
    } else if ( (msg.value >= 0.005 ether) && (msg.value < 0.008 ether)) {
          balances[msg.sender] += 9000;
    } else if ( (msg.value >= 0.008 ether) && (msg.value < 0.016 ether)) {
          balances[msg.sender] += 13000;
    } else balances[msg.sender] += 25000;
}
```

How do I implement a blacklist in the first conditional to limit access like so:

```
mapping (address => bool) public blacklist;

 //  TODO:  function to clear blacklist    -----


 if (msg.value < 0.005 ether) {
       require(firstPurchaceTierAllowed);

   //  TODO:   Check if msg.sender is not blacklisted

       balances[msg.sender] += 4000;

   //  TODO:   Add msg.sender to blacklist
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blacklist checking is simple:

```
mapping (address => bool) public blacklist;

//  TODO:  function to clear blacklist    -----


 if (msg.value < 0.005 ether) {
       require(firstPurchaceTierAllowed);
       require(!blaclist[msg.sender]);
       balances[msg.sender] += 4000;
       blacklist[msg.sender] = true;
 }
```

The clearing of the blacklist will be expensive you need to save in an array the blacklisted addresses and then delete the entries in the mapping. However, I can not see why is necessary to clear the blacklist. you can change the status of each subject at a time when they fulfill your criteria for being whitelisted.

Hope this help